# get_the_excerpt on mobile still displays continue reading

Tags: filters, mobile, excerpt

I'm writing a plugin where I'm using the excerpt field as just another field. In order to get rid of the 'Continue Reading' Link, I'm removing all possible theme filters:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this, 'run_plugin_setup' ) );

public function run_plugin_setup() {
    if ( get_post_type() !== $this->get_post_type() ) {
        remove_all_filters( 'get_the_excerpt' );
        remove_all_filters( 'excerpt_more' );
    }
}
```

This works perfectly on desktop and iPad versions, however on a mobile phone, the dreaded 'Continue Reading -->' is still there and I cannot get rid of it...

Comment: What theme do you use?

Comment: it's based off of twentyten, but I switched to different themes and it didn't make a difference...

Comment: "Continue Reading -->" doesn't look like a string coming from core and it is strange for it to persist regardless of theme. Are you certain of that? Some browsers heavily cache feeds when viewed and it can cause issues with tracking changes.

Comment: I thought it was a caching issue too, I checked on devices that never been to that page, turned on private browsing etc. For now I have overwritten it, but I still have no idea where it's coming from...